# Proguard with Ormlite "no such column"

Tags: android, proguard, ormlite

I'm having a hard time getting Ormlite to work with Proguard, it keeps generating new errors.
I'm currently stuck on the following error message, does anyone have solution?

"`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: region.name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT`area`.* FROM`area`INNER JOIN`region`ON`area`.`region_id`=`region`.`a`ORDER BY region.name ASC`"

Proguard configuration

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Ormlite  ----------
-libraryjars libs/ormlite-android-4.42.jar 
-libraryjars libs/ormlite-core-4.42.jar 

-keepattributes Signature
-keep class <packagename>.db.** { *; }

-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding columnName to the DatabaseField annotation solved my problem.
@DatabaseField(columnName = "")

Answer (score 0):

add `keepclassmembers` to your model classes :

```
-keepclassmembers class <packagename>.db.** { *; }
```